# How to interrupt last command in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm poking around with node.js and I ran a command like this:

```
myEvilString
```

So it should output the string's value, however, it turns out `myEvilString` is a really really long string and now my node console doesn't stop outputing the string.

Is there a way to interrupt node.js's console so that it stops outputing my string? I tried ctrl+c (bash's equivalent) but it didn't work.

note: I don't want to close the terminal because I already have some analysis made on that file and don't want to lose my variables

Comment: you can close your terminal using task manger

Comment: Edited question to clarify

Comment: on windows or linux ?

Comment: windows, but shouldn't node.js' interactive console be the same?

Comment: in task manager stop "evented I/O for v8 javascript"

Comment: yes, it should be the same but there might be different ways of stop a process. Did you try ctrl+d ?

Comment: nothing happened with ctrl+d

Comment: actually, I tried it on another window and it closed the window after the work was done, that loses the variables I had defined previously

Answer (score -1):

Go to Task manager -> Processes

Right click on node.exe -> End Process